# how do I lock callback class in async multithreaded crawler?

Tags: c#, .net, http, asynchronous

I wrote a crawler which uses a user loaded list of words to perform multiple searches on a  site and parse each resulting page.

To achieve this, I wrote a main method which loops through the list of words, sending multiple http get requests asynchronously (using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem) to obtain all pages of results for the current word until no more results are found, and then moves on to the next word.

The callback function accesses a public static class with a static method that parses the returned html and acts accordingly. Right now, I have it locking on the class type each time something accesses the method:

```
    static class Parser
{
    public static string ResponseAsString(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        lock (typeof(Parser))
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream;
                if (response == null || (stream = response.GetResponseStream()) == null) return string.Empty;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch { return string.Empty; }
        }
    }

    public static void CallbackMethod_ParseData(string html)
    {
        lock (typeof(Parser))
        {
            //Do some work here
        }
    }
}
```

So down to my question: how can I more efficiently lock the class and notify waiting threads when the lock is released, or should I not make Parser a static class and instead let each ThreadPool thread instantiate its own instance of this class?

Thanks so much for your help,

-still learning

Comment: sorry im new here...and i cant upvote anyone cause i dont have enough rep

Comment: Well I feel like a jerk now haha. Sorry about that I forgot there's a minimum point requirement to upvote. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locks aren't necessary.  Static methods are thread-safe as long as they aren't sharing static data, which according to your example, they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I don't think there's any reason to have the lock at all.

Comment: How about if I make a call in CallbackMethod_ParseData to another static class (Globals) which contains a List object. This method is called "Globals.AddToList" and uses lock (ListObj). How can I make that more efficient, if at all?

Comment: I don't believe you can. It sounds like in that case you're actually accessing a shared resource so a lock is necessary in that case. I wouldn't worry so much about efficiency as much as just handling threads properly.